# Laravel GroupBy Relationship Column Count

Tags: laravel, count, sql-order-by, relationship

I know similar question has be asked before, but I cant find answer.
**My Question**
An *Order* has multiple *Poducts*. Poduct has column "Category".
How to find number of orders per category?
To get the result ?:

```
[
    "ctegory_4" => 55, //(Orders count)
    "ctegory_2" => 22,
    "ctegory_3" => 11
]
```

This is close, but I need somehow pluck and groupBy results...

```
$ordersPerCategories = Order::with(['products' => function($q){
     $q->select('category', DB::raw('count(*) as total'), 'product_id');
   }])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an answer, I don't know why it was removed ... 
**Answer:**

```
$orders = DB::table('orders')
    ->join('order_product', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_product.order_id')
    ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'order_product.product_id')
    ->select('products.category', DB::raw('count(DISTINCT orders.id) as total'))
    ->groupBy('products.category')
    ->orderBy('total', "DESC")
    ->pluck('total', 'category');
```